# Behat/Mink Unable to simulate click on button in footer

Tags: javascript, behat, mink

Attempts to use the "Then I press" (for buttons) or "Then I follow" (for links) regex for items in the footer fails with error "element/link with id|link|name was not found.. " As an example I found this anomaly on this public site: earthdata.nasa.gov site (Our site is not yet active). The button that says "feedback" on the left of the screen is not clickable (sic).

I am running the test against the selenium 2.29.0 server. How do I extend Mink so that it can locate and "click" on a link such as the "Feedback" button mentioned above ?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Where is your code? Also, the feedback button on NASA's site works fine for me in [tag:google-chrome]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using the id to click the link, you can use XPath to click the link.  XPath is a universal way of identifying objects within the DOM, so it'll always work.

For those who have who haven't used Behat, use this link to read more.  It's basically a wrapper around Selenium's tools.

http://mink.behat.org/

And use this to access the Selenium web automation testing site:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

*EDIT:*

***Ian: Thanks to MacGyver's Pointer HERE IS THE Solution:***

```
/** Click on the element with the provided xpath query
 *
 * @When /^I click on the element with xpath "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iClickOnTheElementWithXPath($xpath)
{
    $session = $this->getSession(); // get the mink session
    $element = $session->getPage()->find(
        'xpath',
        $session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('xpath', $xpath)
    ); // runs the actual query and returns the element

    // errors must not pass silently
    if (null === $element) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not evaluate XPath: "%s"', $xpath));
    }

    // ok, let's click on it
    $element->click();

}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer. Here is a sample implementation inserted above.