# Behat / Mink / PhantomJS not following anchor element

Tags: php, phantomjs, behat, mink

I have a scenario:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Login as a student 
    Given I am on "/"
    And I wait for 1 seconds
    When I fill in "login-email" with "test@student.com"
    And I fill in "login-pass" with "password"
    And I follow "CONFIRM" 
    And I wait for 1 seconds
    Then I should see "WELCOME Test Student"
```

It works up until trying to follow the "CONFIRM" link.
The link looks like this:

```
<a id="login-nav-br-submit" class="button nav-button shadow-bottom shade" style="right: 0px;">CONFIRM</a>
```

Also tried using the id of the `<a>` element but that also fails. I see its not a `<a href="">`. Is there a way to get Mink to follow the link?

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182000/behat-mink-unable-to-simulate-click-on-button-in-footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `href` attribute then there is no link. I mean where do you expect it to follow if there is nowhere to go to? If it has a JS attached that does something, then you can literally click on it instead of following it:

```
/**
 * @When /^(?:|I )click on "(?P<text>.+)" link$/
 */
public function clickOnLink($text)
{
    $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', '//a[text() = "' . $text . '"]');
    $element->click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost worked - just needed to add 'xpath' as the first parameter to find. Marked as the answer but please update

Comment: Yep, I keep dreaming Behat knows it without saying :)

Comment: @IanBytchek - I wonder if you would have a solution [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383870/runing-behat-tests-in-parallel-in-two-browser-windows)?